# How to get rid of binary characters from XML comment?

Tags: xslt, non-ascii-characters

In an XML file I had an ndash as double byte(?) character in an XML comment.

After the conversion with an XSLT script it turned into multiple binary characters and with the next conversion even more.I tried several methods of converting single characters of it but all methods failed, even when worked, they would be cumbersome to use.

Now I thought it's probably possible to kill all those characters at all because none of them is needed. Is there a switch to kill them?

Example (shortened).
How to kill those garbage after "PM reports" in 2nd line:

```
<!--<item aux-profile1="special-adaptations-hide"><?Pub Lcl
vers-inherit="no"?><para><?doc-extra-info-title  PM reports ÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÃÂÃÂÃÂ path performance monitoring reports that are returned by the NE: ?>
</para>
</item>-->
```

Comment: The garbage characters even killed their own presentation.

Comment: When you say "After the conversion with an XSLT script it turned into multiple binary characters" then that is usually not due to the XSLT code but rather due to the wrong use of the programming language and its libraries to deal with strings, streams, encodings. So I would suggest to add a tag for the programming language used to run XSLT and to show the relevant code in that language that causes the problems. XSLT and XML with full Unicode support are usually not the root of character encoding/decoding problems.

Comment: The problem was that authors added these characters. Started probably with one.

Comment: The code which was multiplying the characters then was nothing but <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>

Comment: we even have seen it when authors added some "umlaut" characters.

Comment: I would suggest you provide minimal information to allow others to reproduce the problem, so precise information of the XSLT processor used, how you use it (e.g. the Java or C# or other host language code you use to load the data, run the XSLT, store the XSLT result) together with minimal but complete samples of XML input, XSLT code, result you want and the one you get.